# Masking SpatRaster with SpatVector produces misaligned results

Tags: r, spatial, r-raster, terra

Using `terra`, I am trying to mask a SpatRaster with a SpatVector. For some reason, the masking result `masked` does not work as expected, and it incorrectly retains raster cells diagonally to the southeast.

What's more, I ran `terra::mask` with randomised data and it worked just fine. What could be the problem in my specific case?

Below is a visualisation of my problem: The dark cells are the SpatRaster `masked` and the green polygons represent the SpatVector `areamask`. `masked` should be completely hidden by `areamask` but instead the result is misaligned.

Also below I have attached the code to reach the conclusion shown in the picture. The recreation is a small piece of my original raster and vector data, using the same geometry, attribute values, and crs.

I am using terra_1.7-3 on R 4.2.2 for Windows.

[image: terra::mask produces misaligned results]

```
library(terra)
library(dplyr)

# values for SpatRaster to be masked
cityraster_geom <- data.frame(
  x = c(381625, 381875, 381625, 381875, 381625, 381875, 382125, 382375, 381625, 381875, 382125, 382375), 
  y = c(6672875, 6672875, 6672625, 6672625, 6672375, 6672375, 6672375, 6672375, 6672125, 6672125, 6672125, 6672125))

cityraster_vals <- c(381, 157, NaN, NaN, 595, 186, NaN, NaN, 1117, 330, 70, 70, 1849, 679, 411, 496)

# values for SpatVector to be used as the mask
areamask_geom <- data.frame(
  geom = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7),
  x = c(381500, 381500, 381401, 381401, 381500, 381500, 381500, 381401, 381401, 381500, 381500, 381500, 381401, 381401, 381500, 381500, 381750, 381750, 381500, 381500, 382250, 382401, 382401, 382250, 382250, 381500, 381500, 381401, 381401, 381500, 381500, 381401, 381401, 381500, 381500),
  y = c(6672000, 6671900, 6671900, 6672000, 6672000, 6672250, 6672000, 6672000, 6672250, 6672250, 6672500, 6672250, 6672250, 6672500, 6672500, 6672750, 6672750, 6672500, 6672500, 6672750, 6672000, 6672000, 6671900, 6671900, 6672000, 6672750, 6672500, 6672500, 6672750, 6672750, 6672750, 6672750, 6673000, 6673000, 6672750)) %>% 
  as.matrix()

areamask_vals <- data.frame(
  x = c(381375, 381375, 381375, 381625, 382375, 381375, 381375),
  y = c(6671875, 6672125, 6672375, 6672625, 6671875, 6672625, 6672875),
  xyind = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7))

# Create SpatRaster and SpatVector used for the masking
cityraster <- terra::rast(
  cityraster_geom,
  crs = "+proj=utm +zone=35 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs")

cityraster[["focal"]] <- cityraster_vals

areamask <- terra::vect(
  areamask_geom,  
  "polygons", 
  atts = areamask_vals, 
  crs = "+proj=utm +zone=35 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs")

masked <- terra::mask(cityraster, mask = areamask)
```

Comment: Your extents don't match.
`> ext(cityraster)
SpatExtent : 381500, 382500, 6672000, 6673000 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
> ext(areamask)
SpatExtent : 381401, 382401, 6671900, 6673000 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)`
The xmin in your mask is outside the xmin of the raster. Same for your ymin. That's probably throwing off how you calculated the inner geom bounds for your mask.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @JohnPolo. First cropping `citymask` with `areamask` to have the same extent did not solve my problem:  
`> masked <- terra::crop(cityraster, areamask)
> masked <- terra::mask(masked, mask = areamask)`

Answer (score 0):

Your example works as expected:

```
plot(c(cityraster, masked), main="",
      fun=\()lines(areamask, lwd=3, col="blue"))
```

[image]

If that is not what you are after, then perhaps you can edit your question to explain what it is you would like to happen.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Robert. I do not get the same results using your `plot` command. I made sure I ran `plot` with the exact same data as shown in my question. What could be the reason for this behaviour? Link to my result image: https://imgur.com/a/3RclKSs

Comment: However, I was able to arrive to the same result as you showed here by rasterising the mask dataset first. `> areamask_r <- terra::rasterize(areamask, cityraster)
> masked_fix <- terra::mask(cityraster, mask = areamask_r)`. This is great but it leaves me without an answer why `mask` did not work for me in my original question.